# How to get ID of the author - Blogger

Tags: html, css, wordpress, blogs, blogger

Does anyone know how to get the ID of the poster? The platform I use is Google's blogger.com

I know I can get the id of the posting by:

```
data:post.id
```

But how can I get the id of the author?

Comment: What's the id here? Is it profile link of Author or any unique id assigned to every blogger user?

Comment: Is it profile link of Author!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en#posts, you can't.

You can only only use

```
data:post.author
```

to know author's name, but not author's id.

Be aware that I have found some data tags which work but are not listed there, even though it's the official documentation. But in this case I think it's not possible, because some time ago I also wanted this, and I couldn't find anything.